# Error al ejecutar el comando g resources en nest js

Tags: javascript, api, rest, backend, nestjs

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Tengo ese error al ejecutar crear una REST con el comando nest g resource users. no encontré una solución en la comunidad, me podría ayudar a como resolver eso por favor.

Answer (score 0):

Puede ser conflicto de la versión de cli de NestJS que tienes instalado, puedes intentar probar la versión actual o probar otra versiones anteriores que tienes instalado actualmente.

Comment: Intenté con versiones anteriores pero al memento de comprobar la versión me sale la misma, según npm la ultima versión es 9.2.1, pero a mi me aparece la 9.1.5

Comment: Qué versión de @nestjs/schematics tienes ?

Comment: versión 9.1.5, no puede moverme a otras versiones

Comment: Puedes intentar desinstalar la versión actual que tienes e instalar la versión 9.1.6 de nestJS (npm i -g @nestjs/cli@9.1.6) y me indicas si se soluciona con eso, ya que en esa versión nestjs hace fix de varias cosas. 

[9.1.6](https://github.com/nestjs/nest-cli/releases/tag/9.1.6)
[fix-schematics](https://github.com/nestjs/nest-cli/commit/2e6bd761e06ff1cbb78ec846c52868bb6403a43b)

Comment: No funciono, me sigue saliendo la versión 9.1.5